# Tic tac toe React

Tags: reactjs, tic-tac-toe

I have two components.
Parent:

```
    export default class GameBoard extends React.Component{
      constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
          boardPattern:[
            ' ',' ',' ',
            ' ',' ',' ',
            ' ',' ',' '
          ],
          turn: "",
          winner: null
        }
      }

        handleClick(i){
        console.log(i);
        this.state.board[i]=this.state.turn
        this.setState({
          board:this.state.board,
          turn: this.state.turn==='./images/x.ico'?'./images/y.ico':'./images/x.ico'
        })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>

          {this.state.board.map(function(value, i){
            return <Square key={i} turn={this.state.turn} onChange={()=>this.handleClick(i)}/>
          }.bind(this))}
      </div>
          )
    }
  }
```

Child:

```
export default class Square extends React.Component{
  handleClick = e => {
      if ( typeof this.props.onTurnChange === 'function'){
          this.props.onChange();
      }
  };
  render(){
    return <div className='Square' onClick={this.handleTurnChange}>
      <img src={this.props.turn}></img>
    </div>
  }
}
```

I have an issue with handleClick function. Now when I click on each Square the state 'turn' (adding source image) is changed in every square. How can I make appear image only in Square that I have clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I think the issue is that you can't do `this.state.board[i]=this.state.turn`
You cannot set a state value without using setState.

Try making a copy of the board, update it and set the state with the new value

Something like this

```
const updatedBoard = this.state.board.slice();
updatedBoard[i] = this.state.turn;
this.setState({board: updatedBoard});
```

In your example, I don't see where the board is initialized? I only see the pattern of the board in the state which shouldn't be there if it won't change.

Hope it helps you!